# Android Studio 3.1 Gradle - macOS - High Sierra

Tags: android, gradle

I am having trouble in building the project. It is giving me below error.

```
Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Volumes/Projects/Android/MyProject/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 4331
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: 
Lock file: /Volumes/Projects/Android/MyProject/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock
```

I have tried out to fix it by deleting `.gradle` folder as well as by running `File > Invalid Cache/Restart` command but nothing fix the issue.

### Additional Info:

We are two people working on the project on remote location and managing project with `git`. We thought it might be a git issue and we have deleted all git repo and start new repo from scratch still giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here is the fix

The issue was `SDK` and Gradle version issue after updating `Android Studio` to **3.1**.

## The Fix

Go to `Preferences > SDK` and update if required.

Most probably grade will auto start updating all dependency files and build

This solved my issue.

#### Now Restart Mac/PC

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lock files in the gradle cache by executing something like this:

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" | while read f; do rm $f; done
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already performed this action before posting but it didn't work.

Comment: You can manually delete the `~/.gradle/caches` and restart your PC.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work the solution.. Found another fix. Have a look my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by removing gradle cache file.

> In mac, press cmd+Shift+G and enter this path **~/.gradle/caches**
>   Remove everything under this folder and restart your android studio.